# Why the need to say "titres et domaine compris" instead of "des titres et un domaine compris?

Tags: expressions

> Je compte revendiquer mon héritage, **titres** et **domaine** compris.

The speaker’s inheritance comprises **several** titles and **one** estate. So I’m inclined to phrase the sentence as:

> Je compte revendiquer mon héritage, **des** titres et **un** domaine compris.

I wonder why "des" and "un" are omitted from the original sentence.

Comment: "les titres et le domaine compris"  seems more appropriate (while still unecessary…) You don't revendicate "some" equities, you revendicate "the" equities… also not "a domain", but "the domain related to my  inheritance"…

Comment: Moi qui me demandais si l'omission de ces mots n'avait quoi que ce soit à voir avec l'expression "compris {including}". Merci.

Comment: Oui… ce n’est pas lié. Dans cette phrase « compris » implique qu’il y a autre chose (à revendiquer…), en plus des titres et du domaine… les titres et le domaine ne sont qu’une part de la revendication totale…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not *the* answer for your question, only what I know.

First of all, the sentence:

> Je compte revendiquer mon héritage, des titres et un domaine compris.

is better expressed by

> Je compte revendiquer mon héritage, y compris des titres et un domaine.
>
> I intend to claim my inheritance, including titles and an estate.

The word *compris* when used as an adjective shouldn't be used with words preceded by articles, be they definite or indefinite. This is also the case for the synonym *inclus* used as an adjective, so you won't find

> *la* taxe sur la valeur ajoutée incluse

You will only find

> taxe sur la valeur ajoutée incluse

I am trying to back this up with some links but I failed to find any.
As to the why of that: I don't know.

Second, as Stéphane mentioned in the comment (even if your comment indicates that you were after the first part)

> Je compte revendiquer mon héritage, titres et domaine compris.

would be equivalent to

> Je compte revendiquer mon héritage, y compris **les** titres et **le** domaine.
>
> I intend to claim my inheritance, including the titles and the estate.

not to

> Je compte revendiquer mon héritage, y compris des titres et un domaine.

because there's this assumption in the first sentence that the titles and estate are known.

Answer (score 1):

> I wonder why "des" and "un" are omitted from the original sentence.

Because the sentence has the exact same meaning if omitted…

Not ommiting "de" and "un" here would be a sign of heaviness.